# Republicans racism, study correlation Democrats sound,

Tags: discussion, close-reasons

There have been some interesting actions taken by the Moderators on this forum regarding this question.

[Is racial resentment towards African Americans correlated with Republicans support of VoterID?](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/10818/is-racial-resentment-towards-african-americans-correlated-with-republicans-suppo#comment44128_10818)

> Bill Maher regarding VoterID laws:
>
> Listen, America has had a lot of tricky racist laws. ... But what makes the voter ID law special is that they propose to solve a problem that doesn’t exist. ... But don’t ever accuse a Republican of racism. They just happened to come up with a legal technicality that if applied nationally would mean one in four black people can’t vote. It’s like if you wanted to suppress the white vote so you made a law that you couldn’t vote unless you’ve seen every Tyler Perry movie.
>   Is racial resentment towards African Americans correlated with Republicans support of VoterID?

The question was closed by Fabian, commenting that

> This is a question about motivation, which we declared off-topic in the early days of the site. It's just too problematic as we can't really know what people think.

I completely agree with this assertion. We cannot determine the motives of someone, so instead I reworded the question to completely match the wording of another question on the site. Compare the language in the linked question to that of the newly changed question.

[Does being a strong free market supporter correlate with rejection of scientific claims?](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/10793/does-being-a-strong-free-market-supporter-correlate-with-rejection-of-scientific/10796#comment44046_10796)

**Is racial resentment towards African Americans correlated with Democrats support of VoterID?**

> The following research claims that there is a link between high "racial resentment" (as measured by answers to questions in the survey) and support for VoterID laws.
>
> Here, CPC researchers found an interesting pattern in the data: it is Democrats and liberals whose opinions on voter ID laws are most likely to depend on their racial attitudes. Republicans and conservatives overwhelmingly support voter ID laws regardless of how much “racial resentment” they express. In contrast, Democrats and liberals with the highest “racial resentment” express much more support for voter ID laws than those with the least resentment (see Figure 3).
>   Researchers claim that he has found a link between being a non-black Democrat with high racial resentment and supporting VoterID laws, but no link between being a non-black Republican with high racial resentment and supporting VoterID laws.
>
> I'm wondering if his research holds up to close scrutiny? Does this appear to be real science?
>
> **Is racial resentment towards African Americans correlated with Democrats support of VoterID?**

Since **Sklivvz** was responsible for the edit to the **free market supporter correlation with dispute scientific claim** question, I asked that Sklivvz reopen the question, since now the question was not about belief, but about the soundness of the study in question regarding racial resentment and VoterID support. This is his response:

> the racial resentment question is a mess, as it was **changed significantly** after it was answered. You agree in a comment... I am not sure what you expect us to do.
>
> **that's the reason why it hasn't been reopened**. as for why it was closed, it was explained to you by @MadScientist (Fabian).

Fair enough, he couldn't reopen the question, because it was changed significantly after it was answered. I guess that since it was changed significantly, that a new question should be opened up, since the original question was too different. I proceeded to do so, and sure enough, it was closed as well. This time by the moderator **Larian LeQuella**. The reason:

> Possible Duplicate: Is racial resentment towards African Americans correlated with Republicans support of VoterID?

So, here is the problem. One moderator says that the question cannot be reopened, because it is too different. The other moderator says that the new question is a possible exact duplicate. Which is it? Why can't at least one be reopened?

On a related topic, my answer was deleted as well. Presumably because it did not fundamentally answer the question. I disagree with this position. It explained that the margin of error was significantly less than the change in VoterID support for Democrats with racial resentment. It showed examples of other studies that showed that Republicans are more principled that Democrats, Republicans didn't show any correlation with respect to race in those studies, but Democrats did.

Lucy, you got some splaining to do.

Answer (score 4):

So:

1. I've reverted the original question to the original content. It's about motivation and it should (in my opinion) stay closed.

   - since it has answers, it should not be dramatically changed. I've restored the question so the answers make sense with it!
2. I've reopened the new version of the question, with the new content, since it's not a dupe anymore.
3. I haven't deleted your answer but it was really quite off topic.

Comment: the answer is not clearly off-topic.

Comment: You need to convince others of that.